# Get total transactions to and from an account in ethereum

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I need a way to get total number of transactions to and from an account from block 0 till the current block.

`web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)` returns the nonce of the address i.e. the number of transactions from the address. It does include the transactions to that address.

Looping through all blocks to get the count takes too much time. Is there another way ?

Comment: On any specific blockchain? Or do you want a generic solution to all blockchains?

Comment: ethereum blockchain

Answer (score 0):

> Looping through all blocks to get the count takes too much time. Is there another way ?

There is no other way.

Comment: There are around 15000000 blocks. 
Please check this out  "https://moralis.io/evm-api/" . This returns the count way to quickly to loop all the blocks (/account/{address}).

Comment: In this case, Moralis has looped through the blocks for you.